# How to execute a stored procedure in a multiple step using JDBC sampler

Tags: jmeter

I have the following query which I need to execute step by step (mentioned in the sample below), is it giving me `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`, but same thing working on my Oracle SQL developer tool.

**Step1**

```
SET ECHO ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET VERIFY ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;
EXEC FWA_BATCH_PROCESSOR.SETUTLFILEOFF;
```

**Step2**

```
DELETE FROM FWA_ERRORS;
DELETE FROM FWA_BATCH_CONTROL;
INSERT INTO FWA_BATCH_CONTROL VALUES(10, 'UT1', 0, SYSDATE);
UPDATE FWA_PROCESSING SET PROCESS_FLAG = 'N';
UPDATE FWA_PROCESSING SET PROCESS_FLAG   = 'Y' WHERE PACKAGE_NAME = 'FWA_TU' AND PROCEDURE_NAME = 'DOTU';
DELETE FROM FWA_STAGE_TU;
```

**Step 3:**

```
DECLARE 
j number(4);
BEGIN 
FOR j in 11 .. 12 LOOP
      INSERT INTO FWA_STAGE_TU 
      (ID,
      EXT_ID,
      BATCH_NO,
      OPERATION,
      BLOCK_ROLL_UP_LAST_RECORD,
      LAST_UPDATED_DATE,
      ERROR_FLAG,
      TRIAL_NO,
      TRIAL_ALIAS_CODE,
      COUNTRY_CODE,
      DISPLAY_UNIT_NO,
      GROUP_NO,
      TRIAL_UNIT_REFERENCE,
      PRIMARY_INVESTIGATOR,
      PRIMARY_CENTRE,
      LOCATION_NO,
      PURPOSE_CODE,
      MANAGING_MED_UNIT_CODE,
      UPDATING_MED_UNIT_CODE,
      FINANCE_MED_UNIT_CODE,
      PATIENTS_ALL_SET_UP_FLAG,
      PATIENT_MONITORING_FLAG,
      COMMENTS,
      CONFIRMED_FLAG,
      CONFIRMED_BY,
      CONFIRMED_DATE,
      ROLLUP_ROLLDOWN_PLANNED_FIGS,
      DOC_COLLECTION_INDICATOR,
      VALIDATED_PAT_CAP,
      MAXIMUM_PAT_CAP,
      PREFERRED_LANGUAGE_CODE,
      NEW_DISPLAY_UNIT_NO,
      TOTAL_OPEN_DCF_ISSUES_NO,
      ORDER_INTERVAL,
      ORDER_INTERVAL_UNITS,
      DATA_SOURCE_CODE,
      RANK_SEQ)                  
      VALUES 
      (j, 1, 10, 'I', NULL, SYSDATE, 'N', 102922, 'TESTTRIAL4', 'BEL', 
      j, NULL, 'BELTU'||j, 130262, 124236, NULL, 'PATTR', 'FP', 'FP', 'FP', 'N', 'Y', 'TESTTU'||j, 
      'Y', 999999, SYSDATE, NULL, 'P', 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
  END LOOP;
END;
```

**Step4:**

```
UPDATE fwa_processing SET process_flag = 'Y' WHERE procedure_name = 'DOTU';
UPDATE fwa_processing SET process_flag = 'N' WHERE procedure_name != 'DOTU';
UPDATE fwa_batch_control set batch_status = 0;

EXEC FWA_BATCH_PROCESSOR.SETUTLFILEOFF;
exec fwa_batch_processor.process_batch;
commit;
```

**Connection Configuration**

[image]

**Request Configuration**

[image]

Error Details:

[image]

tried with `update statement` as well, nothing is working ? any clue how we can resolve this issue?

---

After changes: I tried with keeping `FWA_BATCH_PROCESSOR.SETUTLFILEOFF` or `EXEC FWA_BATCH_PROCESSOR.SETUTLFILEOFF`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to remove everything else and leave only `FWA_BATCH_PROCESSOR.SETUTLFILEOFF`
2. One [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler - one SQL statement
3. Either use JMeter [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and individual JDBC Request samplers per statement or wrap everything into [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)
4. The same as 2, one JDBC Request sampler per statement

Additionally:

- Remove semicolons from everywhere
- If you want to commit manually - set "Auto Commit" to `False` in the [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

More information:

- [Building a Database Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)
- [How to Create Test Data in a Database with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-create-test-data-in-a-database-with-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri, I am still receiving the same error. Please check the updated thread.

Comment: I think I suggested leave only `FWA_BATCH_PROCESSOR.SETUTLFILEOFF`, and for some reason I'm still seeing `EXEC ` there. You need to work on improving your capability to stick to simple instructions

Comment: I mentioned above I tired with both `FWA_BATCH_PROCESSOR.SETUTLFILEOFF` and `EXEC FWA_BATCH_PROCESSOR.SETUTLFILEOFF`. I am getting same error with both